# Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have started going through the Angular docs and wondered what is the difference between this controller constructor:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('SomeController', function() {
      this.qty = 1;
});
```

And this one:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('SomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.qty = 1;
}]);
```

Which of the two is preferred and why?
What is the added value of the injected $scope object?

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to minify the code, at that time

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('SomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.qty = 1;
}]);
```

Would be useful to inject the dependencies properly.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer `$scope` vs `this`; it only explains why to declare '$scope' explicitly as a dependency in the array. I'm already checking it out; thanks for help anyway.

Comment: How does this address the question of whether `$scope` or `this` should be used?